# python socket send data after receiving fin (stuck in LAST_ACK)

Tags: python, tcp

I have a python program that is supposed to receive some arbitrary bytes and send them back after receiving a fin. I already was able to implement this as you can see below.

The problem I am having is that the connection is never properly closed. Using `ss -tan` I can see that the connection keeps being stuck in `LAST_ACK` state. This is although the connection seems to be closed correctly looking at the Wireshark packet trace. I have attached an Image of the Wireshark packet trace that is the result of first sending "AAAAA" then an out of order "BBB" and then filling the hole with "CCC".

Looking at the Wireshark packets I think that all packets should be correctly acknowledged and the connection shoud terminate normally without being stuck in `LAST_ACK` state and without doing the retransmissions at the bottom. But I Still would guess that there is a problem with the connection closing packets.

```py
# Echo server program
import socket

HOST = ''                 # Symbolic name meaning all available interfaces
PORT = 6000              # Arbitrary non-privileged port
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(1)

conn, addr = s.accept()
print ('Connected by', addr)
data_acc = b''
while 1:
  data = conn.recv(1024)
  if not data: break
  data_acc += data
  print(data)
print("send data back")
conn.sendall(data_acc)
conn.close()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to the problem. The sequence number of `ACK` on line 56 in the screenshot needs to be increased by one. By doing so Wireshark also stops interpreting it as a keep alive packet.